# Edit multiple xml files in a folder with different files types - using predetermined sequence

Tags: linux, bash, macos, sed

I've a little situation here where I do hope some Linux magician can help me out. I've a a folder `/assets` that has `.jpg` and `.xml` files - a ton of them.

Original xml structure:

```
<annotation>
    <folder></folder>
    <filename>Pro_jpeg.rf.77216510eeb475f923d5bb3bdb22ee11.jpg</filename>
    <path>Pro_jpeg.rf.77216510eeb475f923d5bb3bdb22ee11.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>roboflow.ai</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>416</width>
        <height>416</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>cheese</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>53</xmin>
            <xmax>371</xmax>
            <ymin>224</ymin>
            <ymax>391</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

If you take a look, you can see that within `<bndbox>` tag I've following params defined: `xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax` - in that sequence. It's wrong and I'd like to update all my .xml files with following sequence: `xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax`. So the file would end up like this:

```
<annotation>
    <folder></folder>
    <filename>Pro_jpeg.rf.77216510eeb475f923d5bb3bdb22ee11.jpg</filename>
    <path>Pro_jpeg.rf.77216510eeb475f923d5bb3bdb22ee11.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>roboflow.ai</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>416</width>
        <height>416</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>cheese</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>53</xmin>
            <ymin>224</ymin>
            <xmax>371</xmax>
            <ymax>391</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Any ideas how can this be done? Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit (what I currently have):
So I open terminal, navigate to the folder: cd desktop and call this block. All files are located in desktop/cheese1 folder:

```
for file in cheese1/*.xml; do
    xmlstarlet edit -L --delete "//bndbox/xmax" --insert "//bndbox/ymin" --to "//bndbox/xmin" \
        --insert "//bndbox/xmax" --to "//bndbox/ymax" \
        "$file"
done
```

Nothing really happens, so not sure if syntax is wrong, is it logic or both.

Comment: To edit xml in shell, use `xmlstarlet edit --help`

Comment: @GillesQuénot Yes, but don't I need some kind of loop to go through different file types as well as make sure that multiple objects can be defined within xml file - which increases the complexity and the end result of xmlstartlet is a super complex command?

Comment: Get the basic edit to work first (that may take some doing). Looping should be an easy add-on unless your have filenames with spaces in them. Good luck.

Comment: I know XML just enough to be dangerous, but doesn't "//" represent the root? If that is a full path, it would be one explanation as to why nothing happens.

Comment: Why are you mentioning `.jpg` files? How are they related to your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sed solution, which assumes that all input data is formatted as in the example, and that the wrong sequence is always ordered as `xmin > xmax > ymin > ymax`:

```
sed '/<bndbox>/,/<\/bndbox>/{/<xmax>/{h;d};/<ymin>/G}' cheese1/*.xml
```

Use `sed -i` to edit your files in-place, if output satisfies you.

The way it works is pretty simple. Between `<bndbox>...</bndbox>` lines we save the `<xmax>` line and delete it, then when we encounter the `<ymin>` line, we paste the `<xmax>` line we saved earlier right after the `<ymin>` one.

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- input file is always formatted as shown (eg, the min/max lines of interest are on separate lines)
- OP is open to other solutions besides the given tags

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
flag        {      if ($0 ~ "xmin") lines[1]=$0    # if flag==1 then
              else if ($0 ~ "ymin") lines[2]=$0    # test for indvidual
              else if ($0 ~ "xmax") lines[3]=$0    # strings and if found
              else if ($0 ~ "ymax") lines[4]=$0    # then save this line and ...
              next                                 # skip to next input line
            }
/<bndbox>/  { flag=1                               # set flag
              delete lines                         # clear array if there may be multiple blocks to process
            }
/<\/bndbox/ { for (i=1;i<=4;i++)                   # loop through lines[] array and ...
                  if (i in lines)                  # if popoulated then ...
                     print lines[i]                # print saved lines to stdout
              flag=0                               # clear flag
            }
1                                                  # print input line to stdout
' file.xml
```

This generates:

```
<annotation>
    <folder></folder>
    <filename>Pro_jpeg.rf.77216510eeb475f923d5bb3bdb22ee11.jpg</filename>
    <path>Pro_jpeg.rf.77216510eeb475f923d5bb3bdb22ee11.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>roboflow.ai</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>416</width>
        <height>416</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>cheese</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>53</xmin>
            <ymin>224</ymin>
            <xmax>371</xmax>
            <ymax>391</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Once the output is verified correct there are a couple options for updating the input file:

- if using `GNU awk` we can add the `inplace` option, eg: `awk -i inplace 'flag ... <see_rest_of_script_above> ...' file.xml` otherwise ...
- direct the output to a tmpfile and them `mv tmpfile file.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Using xslt transform via `xmlstarlet`:

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::xmax)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ymin">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../xmax"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT Transform via `xmlstarlet` using bash globbing in a loop:

```
for f in *.xml ; do xmlstarlet tr t.xslt "$f" > updated_"$f" ; done
```

Directory contents prior to transform:

```
a.xml  b.xml t.xslt
```

Directory after transform:

```
a.xml  b.xml t.xslt updated_a.xml  updated_b.xml
```

Updated XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<annotation>
  <folder/>
  <filename>Pro_jpeg.rf.77216510eeb475f923d5bb3bdb22ee11.jpg</filename>
  <path>Pro_jpeg.rf.77216510eeb475f923d5bb3bdb22ee11.jpg</path>
  <source>
    <database>roboflow.ai</database>
  </source>
  <size>
    <width>416</width>
    <height>416</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
  </size>
  <segmented>0</segmented>
  <object>
    <name>cheese</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
      <xmin>53</xmin>
      <ymin>224</ymin>
      <xmax>371</xmax>
      <ymax>391</ymax>
    </bndbox>
  </object>
</annotation>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `xmlstarlet edit` to move an XML element to a specified position
goes like this:

1. insert a new empty node as destination, `-i` for a preceding sibling,
   `-a` for a following sibling
2. copy the contents of source to the new node
3. delete source after copying

```sh
# shellcheck shell=sh disable=SC2016
xmlstarlet edit --inplace \
  --var B 'annotation/object/bndbox' \
  --var N '$B/ymin' \
  -i '$B/xmax' -t 'elem' -n 'ymin' \
  -u '$prev' -x '$N/node() | $N/@*' \
  -d '$N' \
cheese1/*.xml
```

- the source node is referenced by variable `N`, for brevity
- `$B/xmax` may be replaced by `annotation/object/bndbox/xmax`,
  `$N/preceding-sibling::*[1]`, or equivalent
- `-x '$N/node() | $N/@*'` makes a deep copy of source's
  nodes on the child and attribute [axes](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#NT-AxisSpecifier)
  (using a [union](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#NT-UnionExpr))
  (since `ymin` doesn't actually have any attributes  `| $N/@*` can be stripped)
- `-L` (aka `--inplace`) updates the timestamps of all processed
  XML files even if output is identical to input

`--var` defines a named variable, and the `$prev` variable refers
to the node(s) created by the most recent `-s`, `-i`, or `-a` option
which all define or redefine it (see
[`xmlstarlet.txt`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet.txt)
for examples of `--var` and `$prev`).